# How should I work this threading issue in Qt out?

Tags: qt, select, qt4

I have a GUI program , that has a `QLocalServer` inside ,  each time it got a connection from client , it will popup a dialog asking user what to do.

But when there's multiple connection received simultaneously ,  a bunch of dialogs popus all together .. is there a way to queue them ?

I tried to use `QMutex` , but that stuck whole GUI thread.

What's the common / correct solution to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a queue data structure, i.e. put the incoming connections into a queue data structure and then whenever a dialog is closed (say) check if there are more connections on the queue; if yes, process next one. When you get a connection in and the queue is empty process it immediately. QMutex blocks the GUI thread because most likely you haven't spawned any additional threads, and it is actually a callback from QLocalServer and not a new thread that notifies you of an inbound connection.

Comment: I do this all the time with a worker thread that loops and pulls new tasks out of a queue object.

Comment: So you have two threads? The GUI thread and one worker thread? How do you trigger the GUI thread from the worker thread to display the dialog?

Comment: @antti-huima: emit a signal in the thread. The gui connects to the signal when starting the worker.